# Sidekiq worker changing schema_search_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sidekiq

I have the following worker:

```
class ImageWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(tenant_id, id, key)
    tenant = Tenant.find(tenant_id)
    tenant.scope_schema do
      image = Image.find(id)
      unless image.image_processed?
        image.key = key
        image.remote_image_url = image.image.direct_fog_url(with_path: true)
        image.save!
        image.update_column(:image_processed, true)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The Tenant#scope_schema method looks like this:

```
def scope_schema(*paths)
  original_search_path = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path
  paths << "extensions"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path = ["tenant#{id}", *paths].join(",")
  yield
ensure
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path = original_search_path
end
```

When the ImageWorker job runs, it tells me that it can't find an Image with id=7 so the scope_schema doesn't appear to be working although I can take the same code outside of a Sidekiq worker class and it runs just fine.

Comment: Are you using after_commit to ensure the record has been created in the database before the job tries to execute? https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-seeing-a-lot-of-cant-find-modelname-with-id12345-errors-with-sidekiq

Comment: Yeah, I realized it was a race condition shortly after posting this. If you want credit, please post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use after_commit to ensure the database record is there when the job executes.